# Linux Segmentation

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel, cpu-registers

Recently, I read a book called *Understanding the linux kernel*. There is a sentence that confused me a lot. Can anybody explain this to me?

> As stated earlier, the Current Privilege Level of the CPU indicates
> whether the processor is in User or Kernel Mode and is specified by
> the RPL field of the Segment Selector stored in the cs register.
> Whenever the CPL is changed, some segmentation registers must be
> correspondingly updated. For instance, when the CPL is equal to 3
> (User Mode), the ds register must contain the Segment Selector of the
> user data segment,but when the CPL is equal to 0, the ds register must contain the Segment Selector of the kernel data segment.
>
> A similar situation occurs for the ss register. It must refer to a
> User Mode stack inside the user data segment when the CPL is 3, and it
> must refer to a Kernel Mode stack inside the kernel data segment when
> the CPL is 0. When switching from User Mode to Kernel Mode, Linux
> always makes sure that the ss register contains the Segment Selector
> of the kernel data segment.
>
> **When saving a pointer to an instruction or to a data structure, the
> kernel does not need to store the Segment selector component of the
> logical address, because the ss register contains the current Segment
> Selector.**
>
> As an example, when the kernel invokes a function, it executes a call
> assembly language instruction specifying just the Offset component of
> its logical address; the Segment Selector is implicitly selected as
> the one referred to by the cs register. Because there is just one
> segment of type “executable in Kernel Mode,” namely the code segment
> identified by __KERNEL_CS, it is sufficient to load __KERNEL_CS into
> cs whenever the CPU switches to Kernel Mode. The same argument goes
> for pointers to kernel data structures (implicitly using the ds
> register), as well as for pointers to user data structures (the kernel
> explicitly uses the es register).

My understanding is the **ss** register contains the Segment Selector point to the base of the stack. Does **ss** register have anything to do with the pointer to an instruction that affects a data structure? If it doesn't, why mention it here?

Comment: All segment selector registers (except `fs` for thread local storage in userland) contain the same information

Comment: Don't comment your own question, but do **edit your question** to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I make it clear what's the meaning of that paragraph. Actually, this piece of description demonstrates how segmentation works in Linux. It really has implicit objects of comparison--those systems exploit segmentation but not paging. How those systems works? Each process has different segment selectors in their logical address which point to different entries in global descriptor table. Each segment doesn't necessarily need to have the same base. In that case, when you save a pointer to an instruction or data structure, you really have to take care of its segment base. Notice that each logical address has a 16-bit segment selector and a 32-bit offset. If you only save the offset, it's not possible to find that pointer again because there are a lot of different segments in GDT. Things are different when it comes to Linux. All segment selectors have the same base 0. That means a pointer's offset is special enough for picking it up from memory. You might ask, does it work when there are lots of processes running there? It works! Remember each process has its Page Table which has the magical power to map same addresses to different physical addresses. Thanks for all of you who care this question!

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is the ss register contains the Segment Selector
>   point to the base of the stack.

Right

> Does ss register have anything to do with the pointer to an instruction to to a data structure?

No, ss register does not have anything to do with instructions that affect data segment.

> If it doesn't, why mention it here?

Because ss register influences the result of instructions that affect the stack (eg : `pop`, `push`, etc.).

They are just explaining that Linux maintains also two stack segments (one for user mode, and one for kernel mode) as well as two data segments (one for user mode, and one for kernel mode).

As for the data segment if not updated when switching from user mode to kernel mode, the ss selector would still point to the user stack and the kernel would work with the user stack (would be very bad, right?). So the kernel takes care of updating the ss register as well as the ds register.

NB:
Let's recall that an instruction may access/modify bits in the data segment (`mov` to a memory address, ) as well as in the stack segment (`pop`, `push`, etc.)